# Comparing two objects for varying set of properties

Tags: java, compare, equals, contains

I have a data class. Fields can be collections, primitives, references etc. I have to check the equality of two instances of this class. Generally we override equals method for this purpose. But usecase is such that properties which are to be compared may vary.

So say, class A has properties:

```
int name:
int age:
List<String> hobbies;
```

In one invocation I may have to check equality based on name,age, and for another invocation I may have to check equality for name, hobbies.

What is best practice to achieve this?

Comment: Can you complete the example please? What do you mean by _compare_? What exactly do you need to do? Sorting? Anything that could need a `Comparator`? Answering `contains`, so `equals`-based? Something totally different maybe?

Comment: So you just want to find out if there is anything in your list that matches _equality_, given a custom rule?

Comment: Long story short, [Java is missing this functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4837941/1968).

Comment: @Zabuzard, right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate))

You can solve this with the **Stream API**, using `anyMatch`, with your rules basically being defined as `Predicate`s.

For example checking if there is any person who is `20` years old:

```
List<Person> persons = ...

boolean doesAnyMatch = persons.stream()
    .anyMatch(p -> p.getAge() == 20);
```

You can of course also setup the rule in a way that it compares with an existing item, mimicking `equals` a bit more:

```
p -> p.getAge() == otherPerson.getAge()
```

---

### [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html)

You can setup all your rules somewhere else, as `Predicate`s and then use them. For example:

```
List<Predicate<Person>> rules = List.of(
    p -> p.getAge() == 20,
    p -> p.getName().equals("John"),
    p -> p.getAge() > 18,
    p -> p.getName().length() > 10 && p.getAge() < 50
);
```

And then maybe use them in some sort of loop, whatever you need:

```
for (Predicate rule : rules) {
    boolean doesAnyMatch = persons.stream()
        .anyMatch(rule);
    ...
}
```

---

### [`findAny`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny())

You can substitute `anyMatch` by a combination of `filter` and `findAny` to receive an actual match, i.e. a `Person`, instead of just a `boolean`:

```
Person matchingPerson = persons.stream()
    .filter(rule)
    .findAny();
```

Comment: Great contribution, could also collect matches into a set if multiple items can match.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you want to compare always by 2 properties, then with Java 8 it's best to use first class functions.

```
private boolean equalNameAndAge(A a1, A a2) {
    return compareByTwoParameters(a1, a2, A::getName, A::getAge);
}

private boolean equalNameAndHobbies(A a1, A a2) {
    return compareByTwoParameters(a1, a2, A::getName, A::getHobbies);
}

private boolean compareByTwoParameters(A a1, A a2, Function<A, ?>... functions) {
    if (a1 == null || a2 == null) {
        return a1 == a2;
    }
    for (Function<A, ?> function : functions) {
        if (!Objects.equals(function.apply(a1), function.apply(a2))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think you should provide a bit more context or some kind of mini example for this to be complete.